# What is this fantasy series which the author sabotaged to prevent sequels?

Tags: story-identification

When I was a teenager, I heard about a fantasy series where the author was mad about publishers assuming the rights to series and publishing unauthorized sequels.

So this author, who was close to retirement or death, completely sabotaged his world. He revealed that everything in the world was a fake, or completely blew it up, or something similar to that.

It could also have been sci-fi. I know this is vague, but do you know which series had its author completely dismantle the canon to prevent future sequels?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The originator concurs that his memory is of a partly garbled account of Larry Niven's essay "Down In Flames" in which Niven sets out a novel in which he'd have destroyed the known space background revealing that many of its events were fakes (including the galactic core explosion) designed to leave whole species fleeing in vulnerable ships at the mercy of the species behind the fakery.  This book was never written as Ringworld took the series/worlds in a different direction. [It can be read here.](http://www.larryniven.net/stories/downinflames.shtml)